# How do I convert a Python script to PHP?

Tags: python, php

Hello to all python and PHP developers who are reading this article, I am having a lot of trouble converting a Python script to PHP, does anyone know how I can do this?

Code py:

```
import os
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1


def generate_device_id() -> str:
    identifier = os.urandom(20)
    key = bytes.fromhex("02b258c63559d8804321c5d5065af320358d366f")
    mac = hmac.new(key, b"\x42" + identifier, sha1)
    return f"42{identifier.hex()}{mac.hexdigest()}"


print(generate_device_id())
```

Comment: The python code simply calculates a HMAC digest using SHA1 and random data. You just need a HMAC-SHA1 utility for PHP. One option is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Comment: I am a bit confused though. What is your purpose for this code, to generate a random-ish identifier? There is no good reason to use HMAC for this. Just use a UUID / GUID generator in PHP. HMAC is for data integrity and you are simply hashing random data with a static key. This isn't an application of HMAC for data integrity so I'd argue you're using HMAC incorrectly.

Comment: This code in python, generates a device id, but if you put a random String, it doesn't work, even if you generate 1000 deviceid, it has to be exactly with that key, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: A device ID is just a random identifier, at least in the code you provided. There are many ways to generate a random identifier without using HMAC. The key you are using is insignificant since you are only hashing randomly generated data and not an input. Yes it may produce a random distribution of identifiers, but the cryptographic features of HMAC are not useful for what you're doing. You may as well just `SHA1` a random input. Regardless, you can perform HMAC-SHA1 in PHP using the `hash_hmac` function I mentioned earlier.

Comment: It's unclear what you've tried or what "trouble" you're having exactly. Please show your PHP and explain the specific problem. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. Don't just (effectively) ask us to rewrite the whole thing again from the beginning without any explanation of where you're stuck.